# User ID initialization on Master Page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a site with multiple pages, not necessarily heirarchical. I want to query the user's identity (using AD...) whenever the user first enters the site, and create session state variables for the convenience of other pages as needed. A user could possibly enter the site without going through the default.aspx page, so I thought I'd put the code in the Master Page's code-behind.

On the assumption this is a good idea, versus some sort of static class that maintains this information, I started setting it up, but found the Master Page code-behind doesn't always seem to get fired when I enter the site. Is this a debugging phenomenon, or am I right, and the Master Page is the wrong place to put this code...?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Global.asax class. You'll need to add it to your web app if it's not already there. Once you have it, you can then use the various events (session start and end, app start and end and error) to implement business logic particular to what you need exactly.

I tend to monkey around with the logged in user in the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute event of the global.asax. This will allow you to look at the User Principle (eg - User.Identity.Name) to see who is logged in (or if they're not logged in) and do what you need to (such as set Session information for the user, etc.).

Here's a tidbit of code I've got on one .NET web app that uses the Global.asax for storing user data in the Session.

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState) {
    SetUserItem();
  }
}

private void SetUserItem() {
  if (Session["UserItem"] == null)
    Server.Execute("~/SetSessionUserObj.aspx", true);
}
```

... and then the SetSessionUserObj.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string ID = User.Identity.Name;

  MyUser myUser = new MyUser();
  UserItem userItem = myUser.GetUserItemByID(ID);

  if (userItem != null) {
    Session["UserItem"] = userItem;
  }
}
```

This is just one manner that you can go about accessing a user's identity in the global.asax. You don't necessarily have to go about doing a Server.Execute to set user data (I just did it for other reasons that fall outside the scope of this question).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Jagd. If I understand correctly from my research, the Global.asax file exposes events to my site that otherwise I couldn't see. I'm not sure which events, but I'll continue my research. Sounds like you recommend the PreRequest...event. I believe I can use the global.asax to point to a class that has all the event handlers in it. Then, I can set the session variables in those event handlers?